# How do I change rate of the keys repeat rate through console?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, awesome

So I need to make a repeat rate of the keys, pressed on my keyboard about 30 ms. How do I do it through the shell command, to write it down in my startup scripts on Awesome WM that I use instead of Ubuntu's default GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this in the console:

`xset r rate 240 40`

240 - is a milliseconds delay before repeating starts

40 - the rate of repetition after the delay

Comment: That's incorrect, the second parameter is a number between 1 and 255. The higher the number, the faster the repetition.